# After first epoch my precision, accuracy, and recall drop to zero

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to train a VGGNet model. But when I try to train the model. Accuracy, Precision, and Recall drop to 0 on the second epoch and don't increase.

**Code:**

```
model = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(
include_top=True,
weights=None,
input_tensor=None,
input_shape=(224, 224, 3),
pooling=None,
classes=5,
classifier_activation='softmax'
)

Precision=tf.keras.metrics.Precision()
Recall=tf.keras.metrics.Recall()
Accuracy=tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()
F1_score=tf.keras.metrics.F1Score(average='weighted')

metrics=\[Precision,Recall,Accuracy,F1_score\]

Adam=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=metrics, optimizer=Adam)

from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

monitor='val_precision'

model_file='/content/drive/MyDrive/College/Sem 5/ITR/Models'

cp = ModelCheckpoint(model_file, monitor=monitor, mode="max", save_best_only=True, verbose=1)

VGGNet_history = model.fit(X_train, y_train_cat, epochs=100, batch_size=32,callbacks=\[cp\],validation_data=(X_test,y_test_cat))
```

**Output:**

```
Epoch 1/100
69/69 \[==============================\] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.6982 - precision: 0.3125 - recall: 0.0091 - accuracy: 0.0012 - f1_score: 0.2747
Epoch 1: val_precision improved from -inf to 0.00000, saving model to /content/drive/MyDrive/College/Sem 5/ITR/Models
69/69 \[==============================\] - 227s 3s/step - loss: 1.6982 - precision: 0.3125 - recall: 0.0091 - accuracy: 0.0012 - f1_score: 0.2747 - val_loss: 1.4268 - val_precision: 0.0000e+00 - val_recall: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_f1_score: 0.1939
Epoch 2/100
69/69 \[==============================\] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.4348 - precision: 0.0000e+00 - recall: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - f1_score: 0.2721
Epoch 2: val_precision did not improve from 0.00000
69/69 \[==============================\] - 33s 473ms/step - loss: 1.4348 - precision: 0.0000e+00 - recall: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - f1_score: 0.2721 - val_loss: 1.4322 - val_precision: 0.0000e+00 - val_recall: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_f1_score: 0.1939
Epoch 3/100
50/69 \[====================\>.........\] - ETA: 8s - loss: 1.4244 - precision: 0.0000e+00 - recall: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - f1_score: 0.2318
```

Can someone tell me how to solve this